# Prevent scrolling out of CordovaView in Cordova for Windows Phone 8

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In a Windows Phone 8 Cordova application I'm able to click and drag horizontally in the app and pan/scroll past the horizontal edge of the display. See the Cordova Windows Phone 8 standalone template application:

[image: Panning horizontally past the edge of the Cordova app]

The HTML behind this template application has a proper viewport specification, as far as I can see:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
```

This bug prevents any kind of swipe gesture detection from being useful. The iOS UIScrollView control has a [`bounces` property](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIScrollView) that allows a somewhat similar effect to be canceled.

Is this a Cordova bug? Is there some setting that can be placed on the container of the Cordova WebBrowser such that this panning can't happen?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, but horizontal swipes are still possible. There seems to be a slight difference between the swipe gesture the way my app detects it and the 'horizontal pull' you've screenshotted. With some practice, I can swipe without pulling.

Comment: This worked for many people, but didn't work for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16274074/stopping-overscroll-bounce-in-phonegap-ios

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Two extra CSS properties on the `body` tag fixed the panning problem in both the standalone template app and in the original app I was working on:

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  -ms-content-zooming: none; }
```

This `ms-content-zooming` property does not restrict vertical scrolling within elements that are children of the `body` element.

Comment: Have you faced a problem that the pan still happens when you tilt the screen 90 degrees? On that "horizontal" position this hack does not help and pan happens.

Comment: The app I am working on doesn't support a horizontal mode at the moment. I guess we should avoid supporting it, then.. :)

Comment: Seems in my app that if you grab a child element and pull up or down the rest of the page still bounces rather than just the scrollable area.

Comment: This does not work on Windows Phone 8 with Cordova 3.6.

Answer (score 15):

please use this in the body tag of your HTML...i have fixed the bouncing and rubber band effects.

```
 backface-visibility:hidden;
-webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
 overflow: hidden;
-ms-content-zooming: none;
-ms-touch-action:none;
```

Comment: Does not prevent overscroll on WP 8.1 with Cordova 3.6.

Answer (score 10):

This is a really working solution:

```
 <style>
    html {
        -ms-touch-action: pan-x;
        touch-action: pan-x;
    }

    body {
        -ms-touch-action: pan-y;
        touch-action: pan-y;
        -ms-content-zooming: none;
    }
</style>
```

This assumes your app doesn't have horizontal scrolling (which hybrid native-like apps should not have)

Comment: can you explain this a bit ? why are the `-ms-` directives reversed from the w3 directives ?

Comment: until w3 will validate that Microsoft is using the -ms- prefixed directives, -moz- for firefox and -webkit- for chrome/safari (webkit browsers)

Answer (score 8):

You can add the following code in the MainPage.xaml.cs file:

```
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        .... // some default initialization code was here
        // and disable bouncy scrolling option:
        this.CordovaView.DisableBouncyScrolling = true;
    }
```

Comment: This Works perfect! for cordova 2.5+

Comment: Works great on Cordova 3.4 -- though if you have momentum scrolling and it hits the top/bottom, you still see a little bounce.

Comment: This is not really a solution, especially if you are using `Phonegap Build Server`

Comment: Does not work for me. It disables all scrolling. Should I manage scrolling with iScroll ?

Comment: If you set `DisableBouncyScrolling`to true, it's nearly impossible to use something like iScroll. It *nearly* won't scroll at all anymore.

Answer (score 3):

The right answer is adding `this.CordovaView.DisableBouncyScrolling = true;` to your  MainPage.xaml.cs file, but in this case, you cannot use it for Adobe Phonegap Build as this xaml file cannot be submitted.

Comment: You are right, except combinations of `-ms-touch-action` and others do seem to make a difference. it seems to me it depends on your app's layout where what is needed; and ofcourse, these directives have side effects on interactivity.

Answer (score 2):

body { -ms-touch-action:none; }

Comment: Your suggestion disables all gestures and scrolls, not what the OP wants.

Comment: There is also related CordovaView.DisableBouncyScrolling property

Comment: This disables scrolling everywhere! Terrible!

Answer (score 1):

We used position absolute on the main wrapper and it fixed our use case.

Answer (score 0):

this solved my problem with phonegap:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile/))
    {
        var ieBodyHeight = $("body").outerHeight();
        var ieBodyHeightNew = ieBodyHeight - 55;
        $("head").append('<meta name="viewport" content="height=' + ieBodyHeightNew + '" />');
    }
```