# Stopping overscroll / bounce in Phonegap IOS

Tags: cordova

I am using the latest version of Phonegap on IOS (ipad) and I can't seem to disable the vertical overscroll/bounce on the whole app. I don't mind it on inner elements but it looks rather strange when you swipe up or down and the whole app bounces up and down.

I've tried setting `UIWebViewBounce` to `no` in the .plist however that doesn't seem to have done anything.

Appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 205, accepted):

You have to modify a property in your config.xml file.
Just set the following preference to `true`

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

Comment: Since Cordova 2.6, UIWebViewBounce has been changed to DisallowOverscroll.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/guide_platforms_ios_upgrading.md.html#Upgrading%20iOS

Comment: where can i find this config.xml in iphone app?

Comment: I found several different config.xml files There is one in the main directory and I change it there. But then when I build the app for iOS two more config.xml files are then created, one in the platforms/ios directory and one in platforms/iOS/www. The one in platforms/ios seems to have a lot more stuff then the one that I was editing in my main directory (including the preference for disallowing overscroll).

Comment: Adding this setting to the config.xml in my main project folder fixed it for me in iOS8.

Comment: @ChaseRoberts, config.xml from root folder is for Cordova CLI, and config.xml from www is for Adobe Phonegap Build.

Comment: For anyone arriving late to the party: just wanted to confirm this works for CLI-6.5.0 and iOS 10

Comment: I want to confirm that it does NOT work on CLI-6.5.0 and WP8 Windows-Universal platform. Overscroll persists as usual.

Comment: This is working fine for cordova 7.1.0 and ios 11. Remember in ios project there are two config.xml . Modify both of them correctly to get this working.

Comment: @AnkitJ What do you mean in ios projects there are two config.xml files? Shouldn't there just be one for both android and ios using cordova?

Comment: @Josh Just change the only one config.xml.

Answer (score 21):

The accepted answer did not work for me, I had to set `UIWebViewBounce` to `false`:

```
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
```

Comment: I'm using version 3.4 of cordova so it didn't work. But this did the job:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22294677/phonegappreventing-bounce-only-in-the-main-window

Comment: `UIWebViewBounce` has been renamed to `DisallowOverscroll` and the value has been inverted, yet as of CLI 6.5.0 it does not work for Windows Universal (WP8) apps.

Answer (score 15):

now for phonegap 3.0 above version use below syntex in config.xml file and it will works 100%

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
```

Comment: This answer worked fine for me on Cordova 6.1.1.  @Mr.TA must have some other issue.

Comment: This still does not work on WP8 Windows Universal apps with CLI 6.5.0.

Comment: Idk about Windows universal apps, but this worked for me with Cordova CLI 6.5.0, and cordova ios engine 4.5.1

Answer (score 6):

If you're adding `<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>` to config.xml without any luck, you may be changing the wrong file. Instead, search the entire phonegap directory for "DisallowOverscroll." You should find several instances. Change those to `true.`

Cheers.

Comment: I didn't find any other instances of this other than the lines in config.xml that I myself added.

Answer (score 5):

In config.xml of your project, under preferences for iOS set DisallowOverscroll to true. By default it is false which makes whole view to scroll along with inner elements of the view.

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

Answer (score 4):

If nothing else works, try to remove `-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch` from your css...if you had it!

Comment: The problem is that also disables velocity scrolling.

Comment: Yah, I've been trying to solve this problem for awhile and I basically came to the conclusion that it isn't possible to disable over-scrolling bounce without also disabling velocity scrolling, without mimicking velocity in javascript.

Answer (score 4):

Use this way:-

```
function disallowOverscroll(){
  $(document).on('touchmove',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  $('body').on('touchstart','.scrollable',function(e) {
    if (e.currentTarget.scrollTop === 0) {
      e.currentTarget.scrollTop = 1;
    } else if (e.currentTarget.scrollHeight
              === e.currentTarget.scrollTop
                  + e.currentTarget.offsetHeight) {
      e.currentTarget.scrollTop -= 1;
    }
  });
  $('body').on('touchmove','.scrollable',function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
}
disallowOverscroll();
```

For more details or Tips & Tricks, please read this article [click](http://marcgg.com/blog/2014/04/09/phonegap-steroids-hybrid-native-app-tips/)

Answer (score 3):

In config.xml of your project, under preferences for iOS set DisallowOverscroll to true.

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a way I used to achieve this. but it's not conventional because it's dealing with native coding. In the MainViewController there is a method named webViewDidFinishLoad. Include this
theWebView.scrollView.bounces= NO;

inside that method.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)theWebView
{
    // Black base color for background matches the native apps
    theWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    theWebView.scrollView.bounces= NO;
    return [super webViewDidFinishLoad:theWebView];
}
```

As this is ios native code this'll work in any phonegap/cordova distribution.

Comment: Have you tested this code? It has nothing to so with Cordova at all.

Comment: Yes. You are right. It's objective c code. I used this because every time cordova changes I had to modify code or settings. This way I don't have to.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks For All answer. But If you have issue in windows Phone here is the solution.
Just go to MainPage.xaml.cs file and replace below function..

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.CordovaView.DisableBouncyScrolling = true;
        this.CordovaView.Loaded += CordovaView_Loaded;
    }
```

Its works for me :)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, but couldn't fix it with all solutions I found so far (like editing config.xml).

But finally, simply editing the body's CSS property then it fixed:

```
html,body
{
  overflow: auto;
  height:100%;
}
```

Comment: it changed scroll event bind to 'document.body' not 'window'.

Answer (score 2):

Try This One If you are ionic framework user Abc.html file inside content.

`<ion-content has-bouncing="false">`

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
```

Answer (score 1):

this is what worked for my app running phonegap 3.0:
add the following line to config.xml

```
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Try adding this code in config.xml file of your phonegap app:

`<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true">`

Comment: You wrote this comment in every answer

Comment: So WHAT DOES WORK??

Comment: if (!self.webView) {
[self createGapView];
webView.delegate = self;
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
[[webView scrollView] setBounces:NO];
}

Answer (score 1):

It is better to modify two elements in config.xml as follows:

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
```

Answer (score 1):

For Cordova 7 and an iPhone 7 + iOS 11.0.3, modifying the root-directory config.xml and adding this worked beautifully:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />
    ... (other stuff) ...
</platform>
```

Answer (score 0):

Open xCode -> find and click on config.xml from left menu-> and change  DisallowOverscroll value false to true
Or use this code by replacing previous.

```
 <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

After update the the config.xml I had not luck, if that is your case try this.

For iOS works on iPhone + iOS 11, on CDVThemeableBrowser.m file, set property as **YES**:

```
self.disallowoverscroll = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

DisallowOverscroll does not work for me.

Solution is to ensure that there is nowhere to scroll.

For example, in my case it was `div` wider (it can be higher) than the body like below:

```
<body>
  <div style="margin: 5%" width: 95%;>something</div>
</div>
```

Now, above `div` is 5% bigger than body that cause scrolling. Set width to 90% fixes the issue.