# Ionic prevent horizontal bounce / over scroll on iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, ionic-framework

I have some custom page layout, it work great and look nice on both Android and iOS. The page is long and scroll only vertically. But the problem is, there is horizontal bounce / over scroll effect on iOS.

My custom content page looks something like this:

```
<ion-content>
    <div class="scroll-wrap" ng-if="Ctrl.data">
        <ion-slide-box></ion-slide-box>
        <div style="white-space: nowrap; padding: 5px 5px 0 5px;">
            <div class="row" style="padding:0 0 5px 0; margin:0;"></div>
            <div class="row" style="padding:0 0 5px 0; margin:0;"></div>
            <div class="row" style="padding:0 0 5px 0; margin:0;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

How can I prevent that?

Comment: Please refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16274074/stopping-overscroll-bounce-in-phonegap-ios

Comment: @cfprabhu Thanks for the link. Tried it doesn't work. Even if it work, it basically totally disable the bounce / over scroll effect. Which is not I am looking for.

Comment: Do you need to disable the horizontal bounce on ios?

Comment: @cfprabhu Yes, because the page width is 100% to the screen width. Therefore, it is weird to have the horizontal bounce / over scroll effect when user swipe left right of the page.