# Cordova HTML input fields jumping on iOS

Tags: html, ios, cordova, jquery-mobile, hybrid-mobile-app

I have a Cordova (version 6.3.1) app that is just HTML with some jQuery mobile code. This issue only occurs on iOS version of the app (Android works fine). Every time i press on a text box to insert a text after doing some scrolling, it jumps straight back to the top. The same happens with selecting radio buttons that are lower in the page. I have added a video to better explain myself.

Please [see video here](https://youtu.be/MWXqJACMj7Q)  on iOS 10.0.2

What I have tried:

1) Adding this to the config.xml file for platform=iOS:

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
```

2) Basically everything from  [this issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16274074/stopping-overscroll-bounce-in-phonegap-ios)

Any other suggestions and help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/click-a-input-field-whole-app-jumps-down-and-back-to-the-original-place/10876 this worth trying? This is a post for ionic and i am not sure where would i put that piece of code in a cordova app.

Answer (score 0):

If you generating text field by programmatically you should clear dives using " clear: both;" or if it is not this problem won't happen if you create html page with responsive (better to use bootstrap).

Comment: I added div {clear:both;} to my css but this did not help.

Comment: did you try to implement html page in responsive page