# Getting rid of shadow when scrolling too far on android browsers/cordova

Tags: html, css, cordova

[Scroll Shadow at the top of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJLlx.png)

I'm having trouble getting rid of this shadow when I scroll too far up/down. I'm currently using Cordova to display my HTML, but I see this behavior on other sites in the Chrome browser, so I feel like this may be a property in the HTML. Is there a way to get rid of it using CSS?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to get rid of it. It's a native part of Android that lets the user know they can't scroll any further. For this reason I wouldn't recommend even trying to get rid of it. It's possible you might be able to cook up a JavaScript solution that keeps checking the scroll position and ensuring it never hits the very top or bottom, but that could get ugly.

Comment: Ah. That's unfortunate. I'm making an app with Cordova right now, and the shadow makes the app look completely un-native. I ended up finding a solution specifically for Cordova/phone-gap apps, but the shadow still looks a little obnoxious if I load the HTML page in the phone's browser.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this issue specifically for Cordova/Phone-gap users [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16274074/stopping-overscroll-bounce-in-phonegap-ios). In your config.xml file, you can add the line

```
<preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
```

I'll keep searching for a solution that works in Android web browsers.